# Get IP address from Mac ID in WindowsCE

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, windows-ce, opennetcf

How do I find the IP Address for a mac id in WindowsCE using VB.net Smartdevice application in VS 2008/ VS2005?

I am trying to use OpenNETCF.Net but I am not getting the desired results.

Does anyone know this? Please post your suggestions.

Comment: To make yourself clear, post small code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

You say you tried using the OpenNETCF.Net.dll assembly, but you didn't say *what* you tried.  In C# it would look something like this:

```
IPAddress GetAdapterForMac(PhysicalAddress mac)
{
    var intf = (from n in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            where n.GetPhysicalAddress().Equals(mac)
            select n).FirstOrDefault();

    if (intf == null) return null;

    return intf.CurrentIpAddress;
}
```

My VB.NET is rusty, but I think that translates to something like this:

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation

Private Function GetAdapterForMac(mac As PhysicalAddress) As IPAddress
    Dim intf as NetworkInterface = (From n In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() _
              Where n.GetPhysicalAddress().Equals(mac) _
              Select n).FirstOrDefault()

    If intf Is Nothing
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Return intf.CurrentIpAddress
End Function
```

Comment: from "n" is giving ')' expected and 'intf' is not declared

Comment: If I pass like : MsgBox(GetAdapterForMac("00:19:70:7a:78:e0"))error showing "string cannot be converted to 'OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress"

Comment: PhysicalAddress.Parse is probably what you want, or the constructor that takes in a byte[].  I have no idea what your code is storing the address as.

Comment: PhysicalAddress not having Parse method, how do i pass my MacAddress to Get IPAddress For selected mac address